# How to add Angular 5 application to solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, angular5

Let's say that in my solution `Insig` I have already project `Insig.Api` in Asp.net Core.

Then I've added new empty web project `Insig.Web`

Then I've created web application in Angular via `ng new ClientApp`.

And I've put `ClientApp` to `wwwroot` from `Insig.Web` and I set Multiple startup project for both of them.

Now when I press in Visual Studio `Start` then I'd like to run Api with my angular application. How can I do this?

I'm aware that I can do this using default Angular template from Visual Studio, but I'd like to do this from scratch as template contains a lot of unnecessary stuff.

[image: File structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution [HERE](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1245243/How-to-create-an-App-with-Angular-and-ASP-NET-Core)

Hope it helps someone since in most tutorials is used default template from Visual Studio which is actually old version Angular 4...

By the way in `Startup.cs` there is no need to add lines with `AddMvc` and `UseMvc` of course if you want to have API in another project than Angular as I wanted.

And use `ng build --watch` to track changes.

And don't forget to disable CORS in Api `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseCors(builder => builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
```